# Why is "git log" newest first but "git rebase -i" oldest first?

Tags: git

`git log` output shows newer entries first:

```
+>git log --oneline
0614cce adding d
8bcf445 adding b AND c
1fce972 adding a
```

Whereas if I do `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, the interactive editing file shows commits with oldest first:

```
  1 pick 8bcf445 adding b AND c
  2 pick 0614cce adding d
  3
  4 # Rebase 1fce972..0614cce onto 1fce972
  5 #
  6 # Commands:
  7 #  p, pick = use commit
  8 # etc...
```

What's the motivation for this decision?

Comment: You can log commits in reverse order (oldest first) with `git log --reverse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log`, by default, outputs *all commits in the repo* (albeit lazily into a pager), which is potentially a lot of commits. Running `git log` in a fresh clone of [the repo for Git itself](https://github.com/git/git), for instance, outputs over 48MB of text and, if I redirect it to `/dev/null` to disable the paging, takes almost a second to complete on my machine. The delay (and indeed the whirring of my computer's fans) is quite noticeable if I run `git log` and then press the <kbd>End</kbd> key to scroll all the way down to the initial commit.

Most of the time, a user running `git log` is going to care primarily about *recent* history, so a sensible way to eliminate this performance annoyance for the typical use case of `git log` is to output the log lazily into a pager, with newest commits first. That way `git log` is still "instant" (i.e. too fast for a human to perceive any delay) even when run on large repos. This is what Git does.

`git rebase -i` doesn't really have to care about this performance consideration, since it's going to be very unusual for anyone to use interactive rebasing on huge numbers of commits at once. But another thing to remember is that the entries shown in the editor when you run `git rebase -i` are not simply commits, but rather are *"Commands"* (that's the term `git rebase -i` itself uses). When you edit the lines that `git rebase -i` prepopulates your editor with, you are *writing a script* in a simple DSL for Git to execute: apply this commit, then apply this commit but reword it, then run this shell command, then apply this commit and then squash this other commit into it, etc, etc.

That doesn't *strictly* mean that `git rebase -i` couldn't execute commands from bottom to top, of course; it would be *possible* in the same way that any programming language could require you to write your program upside down. But, from this perspective, it seems weird and unintuitive to even expect the commands to execute bottom to top; that's simply not the convention for how scripting languages work. And besides explaining why you'd expect top-to-bottom execution, this perspective *also* explains why you shouldn't expect consistency between `git log` and `git rebase -i`: one is outputting a *log*, and the other is inviting you to edit a *script*, and these are simply different sorts of text with different norms about how they're ordered.

Answer (score 5):

It shows the commit in the order it will apply them on top of a commit.

It applies those from the oldest to the newest.

You can then (with an interactive rebase) change that order, drop some commits entirely, or squash commits together.

---

Note: be careful if your `git log` is during a reword of an interactive rebase: see "[`git rebase -i` shows wrong commit history after a rebase and force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362522/6309)".
Use Git 2.24+ (Q4 2019).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question =)

Comment: @AD7six the motivation is to show the commits in the order they will be applied.

Answer (score 2):

I agree it's confusing.

`git rebase` will show you, from top to bottom, the commits you're rebasing **in the order they will be applied**.

`git log` will show you, from top to bottom, commits **with the latest ones on top**.  I believe the idea is this allows you to see what the most recent commits are fairly easily.  But it's confusing because new entries are usually added to the end of log files, not the beginning.

As nwellnhof said, you can use `git log --reverse`, then press `Shift+G` to get to the end of the log to read it like a regular log file.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are looking at this from the wrong perspective. The two tools don’t strive for inconsistent age ordering, they strive for consistent age *gap* ordering.

`git log` shows you the past starting at the selected base. `git rebase -i` shows you a new future starting at the selected base.

In both lists, the further you go down the list the further you go away from the fixed point from which you are looking at changes.

Comment: I still think this design choice is confusing but this logic is persuasive and the best answer to the question.  Out of curiosity is this just your understanding or based on actual evidence about the designer’s intentions?

Comment: That's a roundabout way to look at a to-do check-list ;-)